# Linear approximation to find worst case volume of a cone

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Need help with an past years question. The question has given me a function describing the surface of a 3D conical structure. During construction, it is known the cone may be built with up to 10% error in radius and 5% error in height. Due to this, I am asked to use a linear approximation to find the worst case percentage error in the cones volume. I can do the linear approximation fine, but I am not sure how to get the cones radius and height needed to determine the volumes from the given function.

$z = f(x,y) = 8 - \sqrt{4x^2 +8x+4y^2 -24y + 40} $

Answer (score 0):

The key is to factor the expression inside the square root: $4x^2 +8x+4y^2 -24y + 40$
We can rewrite it as $4x^2 +8x+4+4y^2 -24y + 36=4(x+1)^2+4(y-3)^2$

Thus we can rewrite our entire expression as
$z=8-2\sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y-3)^2}$

The only problem with this is that this cone is not bounded and is infintely large so I am going to assume the cone is also bounded by the plane $z=0$

Now it should be clear that for a given cross section taken at $z=k$ for some constant $k$ our cross section would be a a circle with radius $(8-k)/2$ which means that our base would have radius $4$ at $k=0$ and the height of our cone is $8$ since that's the point where our cross section has a radius of $0$